# Why is UFW blocking outgoing connections?

Tags: webserver, ufw, vps

UFW is blocking some outgoing connections on my server, such as Akismet, the spam killing plugin for my Wordpress site. According to [Akismet's firewall info](http://blog.akismet.com/akismet-hosting-faq/) I need to allow contact with four IPs. My ufw rules allow all outgoing traffic. I tried explicitly adding rules both for the IPs concerned, but it made no difference.

Mail on the same server is also blocked when doing a CNAME lookup. This makes the logs, whereas ufw doesn't.

Apache serves pages fine, and I can get in over SSH, etc in accordance with ufw's inbound rules.

Clearly I've just got ufw set up wrong, as everything works fine when I disable ufw.

Comment: Hard to know. Can you please update your post with your ufw rules and a log of the dropped traffic.

Comment: All I have in ufw at the moment is `Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
25/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
`

Comment: how do you know that akismet is being blocked by ufw, if it's not showing in your logs?   It seems more likely that it's being blocked by a browser ad-blocker or similar instead.

Comment: Because it works fine with ufw disabled. Mail is also being blocked, and that one does show up in logs as failing CNAME lookup. I have actually added DNS to ufw btw, but still get the same.

Comment: According to Akismet firewall info "PHP’s fsockopen and gethostbynamel functions must not be disabled (they are enabled by default in PHP)"
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php ... perhaps, for example fsockopen also should be configured. "If OpenSSL support is installed, you may prefix the hostname with either ssl:// or tls:// to use an SSL or TLS client connection over TCP/IP to connect to the remote host."

Comment: I mean some specific ports is used by fsockopen or gethostbynamel, and ufw policy blocks it.

Comment: can you try the following:  sudo iptables -Z  then try connecting to Akismet again.  Then sudo iptables -L -v -n | pastebin which will show the dropped packets.

Comment: Done: http://pastebin.com/a1EBCdDU

Comment: I am not seeing any blocked packets in that output.

Comment: And yet the traffic doesn't get through whenever ufw is enabled. Odd isn't it?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem.  This is to help with the $Ask Ubuntu Clean Up. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: As @Seth points out this is abandoned, but that is not acceptable for VTC as per: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17094/can-we-merge-these-three-qas-about-abandoned-questions-on-main. However I'm going through zero answered questions > 5 years old and flagging them as not reproducible as appropriate. EOL also applies but that is also not an acceptable VTC as per link.